# Serverless with node.js doesn't deploy some dependencies node_modules

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

When I use the cmd sls deploy, sometimes all dependencies deployed as expected sometimes no.

```
package:
  exclude:
    - .dynamodb/**
  include:             # this line fix my problem
    - node_modules/**  # and line fix my problem
```

Is this solution is good practice or not?

Comment: make sure the version dependency is correct

Comment: I want to know if include node_modules/** will deploy everything or just Prod dependencies
For me i want just the prod dependencies not devDependencies

Answer (score 0):

By default Serverless will exclude devDependencies.